# can I add a link in the error message of data annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

I have this property in my quote class, so in Html I'm using an auto complete search, the message display "Customer name is required", but I want to display "Customer name is required, to add customer **click here**" this in case of the customer doesn't exist.

and my link should be something like this:

"click here","ActionName","ControllerName"

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer name is required, ")]
[Display(Name = ("Customer"))]
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I honestly don't know as I've never needed to do that with .net MVC. I would try something like this and see if it works. `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer name is required, click <a href='controller/action'>here</a>")]`

Comment: thanks but, is not displayed like link, is displayed like text                                         data-val-required="click <a href='controller/action'>here</a>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to put it on your DataAnnotation? Can't you add directly in your view?

//view code x.cshtml

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("CustomerId"))
{
      <a href='@Url.Action("Register","customer")'>Register customer</a>
}
```

Comment: is an very nice solution and it works thank you!!  I will code it for my project, but I'm still wonder if it can be added into data-annotation message.

Comment: I think to achieve that you'll need to change the way ErrorMessage is displayed in your view combined with the ideas Diana and mituw16 said on comments.